# Stop listview scrolling when popupmenu showing up

Tags: android, android-listview, popupmenu

I have a listview whose each item has a button. When clicking an item's button, I would like to show a popupmenu has many options (about 8 options).

The problem is when the popupmenu showing up, the listview scrolls along to it so it distract from what item was clicking on.
Please help!

My code for showing the popup menu:

```
// 'view' is the button in a row
private void showPopupMenu(final View view){ 
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getContext(), view);
    popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_popup, popupMenu.getMenu());
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            if (mMenuItemClickListener != null){
                int position = (int) view.getTag();
                return mMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick(item, (int) getItemId(position), position);
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
    popupMenu.show();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a Context Menu? It will act like a popup but should lock the ListView into position.

Comment: thanks @Squonk, I used to use context menu, but popupmenu is a better design and experience imo.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method like below:

```
private void stopScroll(AbsListView view)
{
    try
    {
        Field field = android.widget.AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mFlingRunnable");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object flingRunnable = field.get(view);
        if (flingRunnable != null)
        {
            Method method = Class.forName("android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable").getDeclaredMethod("endFling");
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(flingRunnable);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Whenever/wherever you want to stop scrolling just call this method like this `stopScroll(listView);`

Comment: does it work for you? Mine it doesn't work, I call stopScroll() before and after calling showPopupMenu() but it still scrolls when the popupmenu showing. I use appcompat v7 for popupmenu.